# Bluetooth speaker for vacation rental - pairing limit

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to provide a Bluetooth speaker for my guests. Each week there is a different guest. Is there a limit to the number of Bluetooth pairings?

Comment: Completely depends on the device model. Whatever the limit is, when they reach their max, they almost all will forget the oldest pairing when a new one is added.

Answer (score 1):

There's no defined limit for this and it all depends on the actual device. I would expect it to be unlimited, depending on how the device has implemented it's list of paired devices.  There's nothing in the Bluetooth spec to limit this.

For reference, the spec limits the number of active connections to 7, but that's not what you're asking.